# Почему появляется белый квадрат около игрока? PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Ищу ищу, не могу найти. Все, что было в интернете попробовал, ничего не помогло.
Может вы знаете проблему?

```
import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
weight = 1200
height = 640
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((weight,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Elinder Game")
avatar = pygame.image.load("images/avatar.png").convert()
pygame.display.set_icon(avatar)
background = pygame.image.load("images/bg.jpg").convert()
walk_right = [
    pygame.image.load("images/catrunright2.png").convert(),
    pygame.image.load("images/catrun3right.png").convert(),
    pygame.image.load("images/catrun4right.png").convert(),
    pygame.image.load("images/catrun5right.png").convert()
]
walk_left = [
    pygame.image.load("images/catrunleft2.png").convert(),
    pygame.image.load("images/catrunleft3.png").convert(),
    pygame.image.load("images/catrunleft4.png").convert(),
    pygame.image.load("images/catrunleft5.png").convert(),
]
player_stay = pygame.image.load("images/catstay1.png").convert()
player_anim = 0
bg_x = 0
player_speed = 20
playerx = 150
playery = -10
jump = False
jump_count = -7



running = True
while running:
    display.blit(background, (0,0)) 
    # display.blit(background, (bg_x + 1200,0))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        display.blit(walk_right[player_anim], (playerx, playery))
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        display.blit(walk_left[player_anim], (playerx - 50, playery + 5))
    else:
        display.blit(player_stay, (playerx - 50, playery + 5))
    
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playerx < 1000:
        playerx += player_speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerx > 50:
        playerx -= player_speed
    if player_anim == 4 or player_anim == 2:
        player_anim = 0
    else:
        player_anim += 1

    bg_x -= 20
    if bg_x == -1200:
        bg_x = 0
        

    if not jump:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            jump = True
    else:
        if jump_count <= 7:
            if jump_count < 0:
                playery -= (jump_count ** 2) // 2
            else:
                playery += (jump_count ** 2) // 2
            jump_count += 1
        else:
            jump = False
            jump_count = -7

    pygame.display.update()
    for exitt in pygame.event.get():
        if exitt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: Не понятно что за белый квадрат, добавьте скриншот хотя бы. Может у вас просто картинка игрока без прозрачности.

Comment: добавил картинку

Comment: Вы бы скриншот окна показали хотя бы. Или скажите почему белый фон) а то белый квадрат) Вы хотели наверное спросить почему какой-то цветной квадрат появляется на моём белом фоне.